# Imprimir sem janela de confirmação em PHP, Javascript ou Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, impressão

Tenho uma impressora térmica Zebra TLP 2844 não-fiscal, e estou desenvolvendo um programa de geração de senhas para imprimir nessa impressora.

Estou usando as funções `printer_`.

Tentei o seguinte código de exemplo:

```
<?php
   $handle = printer_open();
   printer_write($handle, "Testando...");
   printer_close($handle);
?>
```

Mas não está imprimindo o texto do "printer_write". O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Eu preciso imprimir sem abrir a janela de escolha da impressora, por isso pensei nesse método. Alguém poderia me indicar outro?

Comment: Só uma observação... Já pensou em usar alguma linguagem de programação mesmo para isto? Dificilmente linguagens feitas para _scripts_, como PHP, vão dar o controle que você deseja para este tipo de aplicação (há quem faça "softwares" em PHP, mas é como pegar uma faca para desparafusar um gabinete de PC). Se tiver conhecimento em alguma coisa como C, C++, C#, Delphi, ou similares, e estiver começando a fazer o aplicativo ainda, talvez compense repensar desde o início. Lembrando que nada impede de você ter um executável que interaja com sua aplicação remota em PHP, transparentemente.

Comment: A impressora está definida como Impressora Padrão?

Comment: Geralmente para imprimir precisa enviar o comando correto. O texto plano, tem impressoras que não sai. Precisa de ver o manual dos comandos da impressora.

Comment: Como disse o @Tony, fundamental ler o manual da impressora. Muito provavelmente com uma aplicação rodando localmente, você terá controle total sobre a saída, inclusive aproveitando a formatação nativa dela, com alta velocidade de impressão. Usando impressão pelo driver gráfico normal do windows, ou mesmo texto puro, perde-se quase tudo que a impressora fornece de recurso nativo (isso se conseguir imprimir).

Answer (score 4):

No Firefox é uma questão de configurar o `print.always_print_silent`:

- coloque na barra de URL: `about:config`
- procure por essa config e marque como `true`
- se não existir, clique com o botão direito e peça "Nova" -> "sim/não", adicionando o nome da config e o valor
- depois disso, o JS `window.print()` vai direto pra impressora sem o diálogo de confirmação

Para o FF, também tem este add-on:

> [**JS Print Setup**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/)
>   *Client side Javascript printer settings. This extension implements print setup from CS Javascript, similar of MeadCo's ScriptX ActiveX control for Internet Explorer.*

No Internet Explorer, aparentemente [é possível usar VisualBasic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12536370/1287812):

```
<script language='VBScript'>
Sub Print()
       OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
       OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
       OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
       call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
End Sub
document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>
```

Referencias:

- [JavaScript Print: Bypass Printer Dialog in IE and Firefox](http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/05/09/javascript-print-bypass-printer-dialog-in-ie-and-firefox/)
- [Local print from browser without the print dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10211938/1287812)
- [HTML / Javascript One Click Print (no dialogs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9213660/1287812)
- [Print a page on local using php (javascript) without Windows print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4077832/1287812)
- [Raw Data Printing without dialog from PHP / JAVASCRIPT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6030674/1287812)
- [javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4292373/1287812)

Comment: Anedota: o comentário mais comum que vi é *"Era o que faltava, já imaginou aqueles popups saltando da impressora sem aviso?"*. Obviamente, para uso interno numa organização a questão é totalmente válida.

Comment: Imagina uma senhora indo pegar a senha e sai um banner vertical do tipo "Enlarge your p***s now!" da impressora, bem na hora.

Comment: @Bacco publicidade interativa. Ainda bem que não era uma *impressora 3D*

Answer (score 2):

Parece que faltou você iniciar o trabalho de impressão.

Exemplo:

```
<?php    
    //$handle = printer_open("HP Deskjet 930c");  // http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printer-open.php
    $handle = printer_open();

    printer_start_doc($handle, "Document name");        
    printer_start_page($handle); // Start page 1
    // here goes the content of page 1 via printer_write
    printer_write($handle, "A37,503,0,1,2,3,N,PRINTED USING PHP\n");
    printer_end_page($handle); // Close page 1

    //printer_start_page($handle); // Start page 2
    // here goes the content of page 2 via printer_write
    //printer_end_page($handle); // Close page 2

    printer_end_doc($handle);
    printer_close($handle);
?>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217694/194717

Answer (score 1):

Tente o **jzebra** (qz-print), para enviar comandos diretos para a impressora.

https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/

Exemplo de uso:

```
<input type=button onClick="print()" value="Print">
<applet id="qz" name="QZ Print Plugin" code="qz.PrintApplet.class" archive="./qz-print.jar" width="100" height="100">
      <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>

<script>
      function print() {
         var qz = document.getElementById('qz');
         qz.append('A37,503,0,1,2,3,N,PRINTED USING QZ-PRINT\n');
         // ZPLII
         // qz.append('^XA^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDPRINTED USING QZ-PRINT^FS^XZ');  
         qz.print();
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Lembrando que o jzebra depende de um applet java na máquina.